# How to make :hover effect in a responsive thumbnails gallery

Tags: css, thumbnails

I'm trying to make a `:hover` effect like http://studionudge.com/work.

I have three thumbnails, each with a width of 30% and 5% margin. Because of the percentages I have no fixed width and it's a lot harder to make it work. I can't make the hover appear or center the text.

Is that possible?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="thumnails">
  <div class="thumb1">
    <div id="mask">
      <div class="thumb-title"><h3>Project title</h3></div>
    </div>
    <img src="images/work.jpg">
  </div> 
</div><!-- #thumbnails -->
```

And my CSS:

```
#thumbnails {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#thumb1 {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

#mask {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}

#thumb1:hover #mask {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

#thumb1 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.thumb-title {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When hovering over mask, you're not hovering over thumb1, which is probably the reason it's not working. The site you're revering to is a good example of how to do it. The percentages shouldn't be a problem.